# Generalized Eigen vectors of matrix pair

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How to find the generalized eigenvalues and vector matrices ($D$ and $C$) for matrix pair ($A^HA,B^HB$) such that $C^HA^HAC=D$ and $C^HB^HBC=I$? The main idea is to find a matrix $C$ that diagonalize $A^HA$ and $B^HB$. Thank you.

I found that $A^HA$($B^HB$)^(-1)$=D$ is that true? So when I calculate $D$ which is the eigenvalues i can find $C$ which is the eigen vectors of $A^HA$.